# контроллер laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

подскажите для чего resource в документации не понял для чего он

```
php artisan make:controller PhotoController --resource
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Он делает шаблон контроллера с методами для CRUD, которые Вы будете писать сами, а именно:

- вывод
- получение
- создание
- обновление
- удаление

Фича полезная, если Вам лень это делать самому, больше ничего оно в себе не несет.

Comment: то есть, я хочу создать контроллер для работы с пользователями, где буду их создавать, удалять, блокировать, изменять и если напишу так php artisan make:controller UserController --resource то он создаст готовый набор для работы?

Comment: Он создаст заглушки под методы, логику которых Вы будете писать сами. Это используется только когда вы знаете, что у Вас будут такие методы, и чтобы не писать их самому руками - Laravel сделает заглушки за Вас

Comment: спасибо за разъяснение

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста)

Comment: еще вопрос в чем отличие edit от update?

Comment: ни в чем, называйте методы как Вам нравится

Comment: просто если в создание контроллера дописать resource то он создает набор с edit и update

Comment: Возможно метод edit - для показа формы редактирования. Не знаю точно, всегда создаю руками, почитайте подробнее тут - https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers#resource-controllers